# #<Mongoid::Locker::LockError: could not get lock> in mongoid-locker rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, locking

I applied **"mongoid-locker"** gem on my app but during concurrent request it got failed and got error "LockError: could not get lock".So can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

By default, with_lock does not wait for other locks to complete, so if you actually have a concurrent access, you will get the LockError raised if you don't tell it to wait.

Try it like so:

```
object = Object.first
object.with_lock wait:true do
  object.foo = "bar"
  object.save!
end
```